# Importing Data from CSV to XLSM

Tags: vba, excel

Following is the macro code for my application to get the data from a CSV file to an Excel file. It is located in the same location. But I am unable to import the data.

It is giving an error:

> Runtime Error 1004 Method 'Range of object' _Global' failed.

Excel VBA based application code:

```
Sub LoadFromFile()
Dim fileName As String
Dim folder As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim dest As String


If IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) = True Then
    lastRow = 1
Else: If IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) = False Then GoTo Line1x
Line1x:
With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End With
        End If
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Clear

dest = "$A$" & lastRow
folder = "C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\repairrequest\database.csv"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
    .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder, Destination:=Range("dest"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: Line 22 or .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder, Destination:=Range("dest"))

Comment: You just need `Range(dest)` as `dest` is a string variable not a named range.

Comment: New err: 438 Object doesn't support this property or method. 
Range is always in ("   ")

Comment: Quotes around a variable is a no-go; you also need to save the lastRow long as part of the string to include a quotation around it as part of dest.  You also could have done: .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder, Destination:=Range("$A$" & lastRow))

Comment: when I write only dest, it says type mismatch.

Comment: @RahilkhanPathan was editing my comment as you sent yours.  See the comment about dest, but you should probably use the other suggestion, do not use dest at all and carry in your lastRow

Comment: @Cyril 
Holy moly it works, I am sure I have already tried that. But WORKS now.
THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was solved in the comments

```
.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder, Destination:=Range("$A$" & lastRow))
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why this worked but the variable approach didn't. Doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: @SJR I tried to explain that in the comments... I've had this happen to me once before.  Dim dest as String, dest = "" & "$A$" &  lastRow & "", that way it fits the Range("") model.  It's still better to Dim dest as Range, Set dest = ...

Comment: Thanks Cyril, yes agreed.